# A conjecture involving the equation $x^n+y^n+z^n= (x+y)^n$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Given $x,y,z,n\in\mathbb{N}$,  $x,y,z,n>0$, and $x\neq y$, my conjecture is that

> $$
> (x+y+z)^n-(x+z)^n-(y+z)^n=0 \Longrightarrow x^n+y^n+z^n-(x+y)^n=0,
> $$

where one can easily recognize Fermat's equation among the hypotheses.

My ultimate goal is to find the *structural connection* between these two equations, without supplementary knowledge (e.g. we know that $(x+y+z)^n-(x+z)^n-(y+z)^n=0\Rightarrow n\leq 2$). This means, for instance, to find a way to transform the first equation into the second one, e.g. by an appropriate change of variables, showing that the two equations admit the same solutions. Hence, the conjecture.

However, I tried to prove such statement by means of the triangular inequality and the binomial expansion, also by *reductio ad absurdum*. But I could not find a way through this, therefore

> Can you suggest some idea or technique to prove or disprove such statement, **without using the fact that we know that $(x+y+z)^n-(x+z)^n-(y+z)^n=0\Rightarrow n\leq 2$?**

This post is clearly linked to this one [Literature about the equation $x^m+y^m+z^m=(x+y)^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2836149/559615).

NOTE: This post is a correction of a previous one, that I deleted because of errors pointed out by a kind user. Sorry for the inconvenience!
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but it's quite easy to show that $\operatorname{rad}(n)\mid z$

Comment: @Mastrem Thanks for your comment. Only, I am not familiar with the notation. What does it mean? Thanks for your courtesy!

Comment: $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the radical of $n$, the largest squarefree divisor of $n$. A squarefree number is a number not divisible by any squares. The radical of $n$ is also the product of all distinct primes dividing $n$. For instance, $\operatorname{rad}(4)=2$, $\operatorname{rad}(12)=6$ and $\operatorname{rad}(10)=10$

Comment: @Mastrem Thanks! And what does the symbol $| z$ mean?

Comment: $a\mid b$ means that $a$ divides $b$

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I didn't know!

Comment: What makes you think there is such "structural connection"? The implication may be true without any useful way to convert one equation to the other. For example $x^3+y^4=7 \Longrightarrow x^n+y^n+z^n-(x+y)^n=0$ is true but the equations are not connected in any meaningful way. The implication is simply true because the left side is always false.

Comment: I am not sure to have understood your observation. In your example, the hypothesis contains two different powers (3 and 4), whereas my problem requires the same power $n$. Please, can you rephrase your comment? Thanks!

Comment: Point is that having implication which is true does not necessarily mean there is some deep connection between the two sides of implication. For example I can say *if Albert Einstein is alive, then I am $200$ years old*. This implication is clearly true, though there is no connection between its two sides. For this reason implications where left side is false are usually quite uninteresting.

Comment: Note that $1^3+8^3+6^3=(1+8)^3$, so there do exist solutions for $n=3$

Comment: @Mastrem Sorry for late reply! I wonder if you can explain me how to show that rad$(n)| z$. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the implication as $L=0 \Rightarrow R=0$. Then $L+R=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-1}\binom{n}{i}z^{n-i}[(x+y)^i-x^i-y^i]$, which is greater than zero for $n>2$ because the term $(x+y)^i-x^i-y^i$ is positive for $i >1$. Thus, $L=0 \Rightarrow R>0$ for $n>2$, without any additional knowledge.